# How to Join table to pull all records from first table in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to pull all the records from First Table and matching records and if in Second Table records exists for that join should pull those column otherwise it displays null for other columns.

Please refer below table StockMaster and StockDetails . My query is pulling ony matching recors ex- only two records and i tried LEFT join too but still it is not working correctly.

StockMaster

```
ID   Name        ISIN
1    Apple       54673
2    Microsoft   78734
3    Google      83456
4    Facebook    72345
5    Cicso       12435
6    Walmart     90998
...
1000  Tesco      9878767
```

StockDetail

```
ISIN    DESC                      URl 
54673   Apple org description     www.apple.com
83456   Google org description    www.google.com
```

Query:

```
Select stm.Name,stm.ID,sd.DESC,sd.URL from StockMaster stm INNER JOIN 
StockDetail sd on stm.ISIN=sd.ISIN
```

Result

```
Name         ID                  DESC                     URL
Apple        1                   Apple org description    www.apple.com
Microsoft    2                   NULL                     NULL
Google       3                   Google org description   www.google.com           
Facebook     4                   NULL                     NULL
Cicso        5                   NULL                     NULL  
Walmart      6                   NULL                     NULL
```

One more case

```
Select stm.Name,stm.ID,sd.DESC,sd.URL from StockMaster stm INNER JOIN 
StockDetail sd on stm.ISIN=sd.ISIN where stm.ISIN =78734
```

In the above case i still want to retrieve microsoft company data but it returning empty because second table does not have ISIN

Comment: MySQL Or SQL Server? What are you *really* using? What does this have to do with Linq and Dynamic SQL?

Comment: sorry , I am using SQL server ..it gave me automatic tags ..i will remove it

Comment: *"it gave me automatic tags"* Stack Overflow only makes suggestions, it doesn't add them. Only *you* can do that

Comment: @Larnu thats right i just added what they referred ..My bad i have updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN`. I dont know why you did not get correct result uaing `LEFT JOIN` but use following query for desired result.

```
Select stm.Name,stm.ID,sd.DESC,sd.URL 
  from StockMaster stm 
  LEFT JOIN StockDetail sd on stm.ISIN=sd.ISIN 
 Where stm.isin = 78734
```

`LEFT JOIN` gives you all data from left table and matching data from right table. So put the table from which you need all the data on left of the syntax `LEFT JOIN` and other table from where you just want matching data on right side of it.

```
All_data_from_this_table LEFT JOIN matching_data_from_this_table ON ..
```

Comment: The problem is happening when i am using a condition to find specific ISIN ex - In Where condition if i find ISIN=78734. I am not getting Microsoft records

Comment: @RahulSharma Then show the exact query you use. We cannot read your mind or see your screen.

Comment: @SMor I am using this query but when i do that it is returning all the records but i want only Microsoft company data                                                                       Select stm.Name,stm.ID,sd.DESC,sd.URL from StockMaster stm INNER JOIN 
StockDetail sd on stm.ISIN=sd.ISIN where stm.ISIN =78734

Comment: Why you are using inner join? See the updated answer. Used where condition `Where stm.isin = 78734`

Comment: @Popeye When i am using the query which you provided I am getting all records ex- 1000 records from first table but i need only one row

Comment: And what is the reason for that 1000 records? You must have that much data available in one of these two tables. Your requirement is not clear now. Is table2 or table1 has that much data for given isin number?

Comment: @Popeye In my first table I have 1000 records in second table i have 250 records . So, I am doing Left join with ISIN .. but for 750 companies for which i don't have matching records with ISIN ...but when i am doing join with AND condition i am getting all records from first table but i am expecting only 1 record

Comment: Dont use and condition in ON for filtering table from table1. Use the condition in WHERE clause for filtering record from `StockMaster `. If you will run exact query provided in the answer then you will definately get the record for only microsoft.

Comment: @Popeye Thanks , actually i were doing one silly mistake after Join i were doing and ISIN = instead of Where ISIN =

Answer (score 0):

Just use LEFT JOIN

```cs
var query = 
   from stm in ctx.StockMaster
   join sd in ctx.StockDetail on stm.ISIN equals sd.ISIN into gj
   from sd in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new 
   {
      stm.Name,
      stm.ID,
      sd.Desc,
      sd.Url
   }
```

Comment: @Svtatoslav The problem is happening when i am using a condition to find specific ISIN ex - In Where condition if i find ISIN=78734. I am not getting Microsoft records